# A better way of parsing a string for numbers in brackets?

Tags: c++, parsing

I've tried searching on here / Google to find a more optimal way of processing an input that I need to handle.  This is an example...

```
[1 5 0 50 100 60] [2 4 1 0 40 50]
```

The numbers are random but I know how many bracketed sets there are beforehand.  Also, I know for certain that the format will always be the same...

6 numbers which are enclosed by brackets

I have something working already where I get the input into a line and I then iterate character by character checking...

1)  Outer for loop that accounts for the number of bracketed sets

2)  First to see if it is a space, '[', ']'

3)  If it isn't, get that number and store it

4)  then start checking for space again

5)  Store the next etc

6)  Till I reach ']' and continue the loop

But I feel like there needs to be a better / cleaner way of handling the parsing.

sample code...

```
    char c = line[position];

    while (c == '[' || c == ']' || cc == ' '){
        position++;
        c = line[position];
    }

    string firstStr;

    while (c != ' '){
        firstStr += c;
        position++;
        c = line[position];
    }

    first = atoi(firstStr.c_str());

    while (c == ' '){
        position++;
        ch = line[position];
    }

    string secondStr;

    while (c != ' '){
        secondStr += c;
        position++;
        c = line[position];
    }

    second = atoi(secondStr.c_str());
```

Comment: @seb but then the OP has two problems.

Comment: I would use `std::istringstream` or `std::sscanf()`

Comment: Thanks guys.  I thought about regex as well but wasn't sure how to implement.  Remy, I'll have a look at both thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'd say that this is too complicated for the simple reason that the C++ library already contains optimized implementations of all algorithms that are needed here.

```
std::string line;
```

That's your input. Now, let's parse it.

```
#include <algorithm>

auto b=line.begin(), e=line.end();

while ((b=std::find(b, e, '[')) != e)
{
    auto n_start=++b;

    b=std::find(b, e, ']');

    auto your_six_numbers_are_in_here=std::string(n_start, b);

    // Now, do whatever you want with your numbers.
}
```

Since you "know for certain" that your input is valid, most aspects of input validation are no longer an issue, and the above should be sufficient.

The `your_six_numbers_are_in_here` string may or may not contain leading or trailing spaces. How to get rid of them, and how to extract the actual numbers is a separate task. Now, since you know "for certain" that your input will be valid, then this becomes a simple matter of:

```
std::istringstream i(your_six_numbers_are_in_here);

int a, b, c, d, e, f;

i >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f;
```

It goes without saying that if you do not know "for certain" that your input will be valid, additional work will be needed, here.

Comment: Thanks!   I'll give this a look.